# Testing node js router with with chai and supertest fails

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test a `post` request that takes in information and saves to mysql database.

Here is the router.

```
router.post('/dbInsert',(req,res,next)=>{
   user = req.body;
   saveUser(user).then((result)=>{
       res.send('All info saved');
    }).catch((e)=>{
       res.send('All info not saved');
   });
});
```

The router works since I tried to post data into it.

So now when I am trying to run the test, it says error. Here is the test.

```
describe('POST /dbInsert',()=>{
    it('should create a new user',(done)=>{
        var fake = {
            Owner : "3",
            firstname : "bla",
            lastname : "wassup",
            email:"unvalid@email.com",
            password : "akhjashjkdadh",
            token : "121212121"
        }
        request(app)
            .post('/dbInsert')
            .send(fake)
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res)=>{
                expect(res.body).to.include(fake);
            })

            .end((err,res)=>{
                if(err)
                    return done(err);
            });
    });
});
```

Here is the error.

```
1 failing

  1) POST /dbInsert should create a new user:
     AssertionError: expected {} to have property 'Owner'
```

`/* Not related to the above question but just curious */`

I am new to this and also wanted to ask, how can the database be cloned, as in not test on my own database but have a fake database that tests this and then gets itself deleted. I looked at spy, but din't know if thats the way to do it.

Comment: For the "Not related to the above" question, I think you're referring to a [test fixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture#Software) . Consider something like [node-sql-fixtures](https://github.com/city41/node-sql-fixtures) to set up your test database fixtures, or write something yourself to setup your test database in your before/after hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supertest test is not behaving like you think. This does not unit test what you sent to your server. This tests the response from your server, so it's not going to be the object that you sent.

```
.expect((res)=>{
    expect(res.body).to.include(fake);
})
```

If you call `res.send(body)` in your route, you should be able to validate it like this:

```
.end((err, res) => {
    if (err) return done(err);
    expect(res.body).to.have.property("Owner").that.equal("3");
    return done();
})
```

Another issue I see is that you're not handling errors properly. In your case, you're sending a 200 in the event of an error, meaning that you don't know when it fails and that's probably why the updated validation doesn't seem to work properly.

.catch((e)=>{
       // Only difference is the message.
       res.send('All info not saved');
   });

Try this:

.catch((e)=>{
       // Now, it will be a 500 to note the failure
       res.status(500).send(e.message);
   });

This is going to timeout when successful because you're only going to call `done` when it there's an error. Just remove the `if` statement.

```
.end((err,res)=>{
    if(err)
        return done(err);
});
```

This should work:

```
.end(done);
```

**The whole shibang:**

```
router.post('/dbInsert',(req,res,next)=>{
   user = req.body;
   saveUser(user).then((result)=>{
       res.send(user);
       next();
    }).catch((e)=>{
       res.status(500).send(e.message);
       next();
   });
});

describe('POST /dbInsert',()=>{
    it('should create a new user',(done)=>{
        var fake = {
            Owner : "3",
            firstname : "bla",
            lastname : "wassup",
            email:"unvalid@email.com",
            password : "akhjashjkdadh",
            token : "121212121"
        }
        request(app)
            .post('/dbInsert')
            .send(fake)
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) return done(err);
                expect(res.body).to.have.property('Owner').that.equal(fake.Owner);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

**To test, I verified that this works:**

```
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  return res.send(req.body);
});

request(app)
  .post('/user')
  .send({
      foo: "bar"
  })
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    expect(res.body.foo).to.equal("bar");
  });
```

If it's still not working, there must be something unseen going on. Try `console.dir(res.body)` if it doesn't work to look at the output.

Comment: did exactly as you said, but still getting the same error.
 AssertionError: expected {} to have property 'Owner'

Comment: I sent back the response from the router like this, 
res.send(req.body);

Comment: Hi Arsenal, I am getting the same errors, maybe I am just writing it wrong, if its possible could you just write the whole test code, so I can copy paste it to see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @MasnadHossain Try the above. It's been a while since I've used supertest, so I'm not 100% certain on the right syntax for everything without messing around with it.

Comment: Tried it, but the problem is now the error, shows Uncaught AssertionError: expected undefined to equal '3'
, wouldn't it be better to see why the array isnt becoming equal to the recieved array?

Comment: @MasnadHossain You could check to see that the returned object equals the object you sent, but I'm not sure if the reference to the object remains unchanged through the operation or if `expect` tests the properties are equal, not the references. I added an assertion on a specific property not as a suggestion on how your final validation should be, but as a "this should definitely work" validation. Once you have it working, you can make it more to your liking. I updated the question with a working example of a tiny app.

Comment: I tried to replicate your example, which is odd I find getting an error like this 
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'bla', since I tried doing 
expect(res.body.firstname).to.equal("bla");

Comment: At the bottom of your question, paste the exact code that you're running now that's not working as expected.

Comment: @MasnadHossain I think I figured out why the body is empty. You're not actually handling the error case, so you're getting a 200, which means OK, but it's really an error. In the error case, you're sending a message but not setting an appropriate status, meaning that the validation passes until you get to the body, which is empty. See my updated code.

Comment: I figured out the error, the database part, stops all things from happening but, if I just return the information before database saving happening then it works. How can I by pass database transactions?

Comment: @MasnadHossain This question is really about supertest, chaijs, and express, and the scope has grown to the extent that it really should be multiple questions. If supertest is now working as expected (it's validating that your route is failing with a 500), you should accept this answer and detail your DB question in a new question. It's best practice to keep questions focused to get to a clean answer.

Comment: Yes true, atleast something is working now, I need to figure out why the data doesn't get send back after the database performs a save..
But thanks!